# Object reference passed in function argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the color of link with jQuery. I get an error when I try to reference to the object.

my HTML :

```
<a onmouseover="loclink(this);return false;" href="locations.html" title="Locations" class="nav-link align_nav">Locations</a>
```

My JS:

```
function loclink(a){
    a.css("color", "red"); // Didn't work
    jQuery('a').find('.nav-link').css("color", "red"); // Didn't work
    $(a).find('.nav-link').css("color", "red"); // Didn't work

console.log(a):

<a onmouseover="loclink(this);return false;" href="locations.html" title="Locations" class="nav-link align_nav">Locations</a>
```

Comment: You want `$(a).css("color", "red")`. `css` is a jQuery command, so you need to make `a` into a jquery object. Your two other lines try to find an element `.nav-link` INSIDE `a`.

Comment: Why not you use `css`?

Comment: What you really want, is to stop using inline event handlers

Comment: ...and to stop using jQuery. And direct css manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function loclink(a){
    $(a).css("color", "red"); // this should work
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onmouseover="loclink(this);return false;" href="locations.html" title="Locations" class="nav-link align_nav">Locations</a>
```

A better approach (instead of using inline events) is to use [Jquery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach an event handler to your links

```js
$("a.nav-link").on("mouseover",function (){
    $(this).css("color", "red"); // this should work
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a  href="locations.html" title="Locations" class="nav-link align_nav">Locations</a>
```

Comment: Thank you ...That's what I needed